# Difference between base, core, extra and community packages in arch-linux

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation

What is the difference between *base*, *core*, *extra* and *community* systems when installing the Arch-Linux?

e.g.

```
pacstrap /mnt base
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are confusing a couple different concepts here. `base` is a package group. It's what many consider to be the “default” package set for an Arch Linux install (and many of the rest of Arch will assume that you have all of the packages in `base` installed—so this isn't really an incorrect assertion).

On the other hand, `core`, `extra` and `community` are repositories. It is not too surprising that these can be confused with package groups (since repos are just large sets of packages). But package groups are meant to associate particular packages with one another (e.g., the `gnome` group contains packages related to GNOME). Repositories just store packages.

Generally speaking, `core` contains packages that are central to the running of a Linux distribution. You should probably expect to have almost all of its packages installed. For example, I have about ⅔ of them installed on my machine.

`extra` are packages that are widely used in running a Linux machine but will not be absolutely necessary for keeping a stable system. For example, you will find `xorg-server` in `extra` (not `core`) because headless machines do not need X.

`community` is a bit of a different beast. Where `core` and `extra` are maintained by the [Arch Developers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/DeveloperWiki:Divisions), `community` is maintained by the Arch [Trusted Users](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Trusted_Users). This group of users maintains the [AUR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository) and moves things into `community` as they (and the community at-large) see fit.

There are other repositories as well (most notably `multilib` and the `testing` repositories), but not all users will want them enabled. In addition, you can easily create your own repository (which is one of the best decisions I have ever made) that you can host locally with a tool called [`repose`](https://github.com/vodik/repose). Additionally, there are some [Unofficial User Repositories](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unofficial_user_repositories).

---

Some additional reading:

- [Arch Linux Repositories](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Official_repositories)
- [Package Groups](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PKGBUILD#groups)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information. &#128512; It makes sense to me now 

Comment: Thanks alot for the links. They were so much helpful :D.